# Key matching for backing track

Tags: soundtrack

I play Native American Flute in the Key of D and am trying to find what key of backing track I need, is it the same as the flute or should it be different, Sorry if I sound stupid but I jest can’t seem to get my head around this theory business.

Comment: You can play a D with a tuner and see what note it thinks it is.  That's the key your backing track will need to be in.  As an alternative, there's software that will shift the key of a recording, so really you can get a track in any key you'd like and modify to fit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about music theory are off topic here. They are also off topic on the Music Practice and Theory stack, but you can get an answer by posting in the chat room there.

Answer (score 0):

In general, with a mono-key instrument like Native American flute, you do need the backing track to be in the same key. It's worth noting, however  that unless the backing track also uses natural tuning, you'll lose that "organic" feel of a natural-tuned instrument.

Originally, all instruments were in a single key (natural tuning). Later, tempered tunings were invented, which allowed harpsichords, pianos and modern keyboard instruments to play in any key (basically through detuning most of the notes by minute amounts).

Instruments like the violin can approximate different keys because they have variable pitched notes, and modern flutes have complex keying that allows them to play a wider range of notes. But a more traditional flute wouldn't have that, so you can only play in D (or in various modes like Dorian and Phrygian).

*(You might ask this question instead on Music: Practice & Theory, it's arguably better placed there.)*